Redocly only show Required Scopes
We are using Redocly to document one of our C# APIs. I want to show which Scopes are required for each API endpoint. Right now the OpenAPI documentation is generated from our code, and we use a SwaggerRequiredScopes attribute to mark which scopes are required by the API endpoint. This is working perfectly, except that we do not want the Flow Type and Token URL and Scopes to show under each API endpoint. Instead, we just want Required Scopes to show:

How do we do this?

Ended up putting this in the Header parameters. See example below:
- name: Authorization
  in: header
  description: >-
    An OAuth Access Token with any of the following
    scopes:<ul><li>`example.scope.required`</li></ul> in
    the format **Bearer {accessToken}**.
  required: true
  schema:
    type: string

